# What is the purpose of the Complete-BitsTransfer cmdlet?

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-3.0

PowerShell and Windows have a nice framework for transferring files called BITS. This can be used synchronously:

```
Start-BitsTransfer -Source \\remote_file_location -Destination .
```

There is an asynchronous flag to run the download in the background:

```
Start-BitsTransfer -Asynchronous -Source \\remote_file_location -Destination .
```

If you just run the job asynchronously, after a while it will show as transferred:

```
JobId                     DisplayName              TransferType             JobState                             
-----                     -----------              ------------             --------                 
cd070594-6103-44eb-b6c... BITS Transfer            Download                 Transferred
```

However, your file won't show up at destination until you run the Complete-BitsTransfer cmdlet:

```
Get-BitsTransfer | Complete-BitsTransfer
```

Until then, your file is apparently in limbo, somewhere on your computer (or in memory?). What is the purpose of this? Why doesn't windows directly place files at their destination as they arrive?

Comment: Should be in a TMP file until you complete the transfer.

Comment: @Knuckle-Dragger : So what's the point? Won't that risk filling up your tmp folder, if it's on a small drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In situations where an event-driven automated process is going to do something as soon as the file is written, it lets you control the timing of that process by transferring the file to temp location, and the Complete process will write it to it's final destination.

e.g. if you were transferring a file to multiple systems to update a piece of client software, and need to make sure they all update at the same time, and that all of them update or none of them do.

Comment: Fair enough, although I suppose it should be optional and at least documented.

Comment: Do you know where the file are stored before the final copy?

Comment: @static_rtti from what I've seen they're put in the destination folder; but are just .tmp files (e.g. `BITE665.tmp`).  On completion these files are renamed to the specified filename & extension.